# What is the best distribution that describe the variances $\sigma^2(x)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

I'm studying a numerical variances $\sigma^2(x)$.
For each samples I have more than one hundred of variances.

I'm looking for the distribution that can describe them. I think is not Gaussian, because $\sigma^2(x) \ge 0$.

The question is: for computing the confidence interval is better use a Rayleigh distribution, a chi-squared distribution or an other again?

Comment: Just to clarify, the distribution is not Gaussian because this allows $\sigma^2(x) = 0$?

Comment: Because I can not have negative results. So the distribution must start from zero.

Comment: Gotcha, had confusion in the request of the question

Comment: Do you know anythingh about the distribution of the data from which the variances are calculated?

Comment: Yes. They are the variances of vertical acceleration that a smartphone sensing when it is rigidly anchored to car cabin. So I have 100 acceleration per second and 1 variances per second. After some minutes (with constant velocity) I have find the features of this variances, but I can't plot a graph with CI negative.